# Inspecting a Docker image that isn't fully extracted due to storage restrictions

Tags: docker

## Problem

I've got this large image, `privateRegistry.com/megahumongo`. The `Dockerfile` for this image is long gone, and I'm tasked to figure out what's in this pancake stack, recreate the `Dockerfile`, and version control it (something I've done before).

My VDI can allow for up to 12 GB of Docker disk assets in the partition where Docker images are put. The image at `privateRegistry.com/megahumongo` can be fully downloaded, but during the extraction process I'm about 30 layers away from extracting it all before I run out of disk space.

```
$ docker pull privateRegistry.com/megahumongo
.
.
.
failed to register layer: open /var/lib/docker/[MORE PATH]/diff: no space left on device
```

According to watching `df -h` during the above command, the partition fills up as the image is being pulled & extracted. After the error occurs, the partition quickly reclaims the space and the image & extracted contents are gone.

I have no access to another device on the network with adequate space for this Docker image. Unless I was going to inspect it via the GitLab pipeline, but that seems wrong...

## Questions

This isn't something I've encountered before and I'm not exactly sure on the next steps. The below questions are meant to help guide a potential discussion. Feel free to ignore them if you have advice that may help resolve my current task.

- Is there a process for partially downloading a Docker image?
- Is there a clean way to prevent the `docker` CLI tool from removing an image that it failed to pull due to a lack of disk space?
- Why do people not version control their `Dockerfile`s?

Comment: That's not meant to be too critical of you personally btw -- I'm sure you're just doing your best in a difficult situation, but honestly, if you fix this then you're just as much to blame as the cowboy who created the situation, and the completely incompetent management that allowed it to happen. Your best course of action is to expose the lot of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `skopeo` to download the image from Docker to a local directory in the format used by `docker save`.  For example, if I run:

```
skopeo copy docker://docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd docker-archive:darkhttpd.tar.gz
```

I end up with:

```
$ tar tf darkhttpd.tar.gz
c04d1437198bc178b49fdb9a90a9c0e362ffbd63c4be5d19fec406d1c9d6a03c.tar
7c79a05ae8188119670b72544d44492b06eb86ed3a5e1b032a2ea9c74eea8a6d.tar
7adbc95cdf8cef4a0bc6bc2f235bbfdf1e31acc18fe4d2127c988fbed6e3add2.json
9dbaa9f818ba4710721ac8b4105da215171029b7124c77cc916e11e2aa6bad2c/layer.tar
9dbaa9f818ba4710721ac8b4105da215171029b7124c77cc916e11e2aa6bad2c/VERSION
9dbaa9f818ba4710721ac8b4105da215171029b7124c77cc916e11e2aa6bad2c/json
ddc7ea7366a22d9a53a77220023064ccfbb737c3c8b4c6fa366d8a5e0717ba32/layer.tar
ddc7ea7366a22d9a53a77220023064ccfbb737c3c8b4c6fa366d8a5e0717ba32/VERSION
ddc7ea7366a22d9a53a77220023064ccfbb737c3c8b4c6fa366d8a5e0717ba32/json
manifest.json
repositories
```

I can then extract and inspect the individual layers (or the metadata from the various .json files).

> Why do people not version control their Dockerfiles?

Because they haven't learned otherwise. Everyone has to start somewhere!